# Search a directory recursively for files listed in a csv, and copy them to another location

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, csv-simple

I have a directory (let's call it "Movies") which contains many files and folders. I have a long list of file names in a .csv file (around 4000 entries) which refer to files which are located somewhere within the Movies directory sub-folders.

How can I search the Movies directory recursively for the files listed in the .csv and copy them to a separate directory ("Sorted_Media")?

EDIT: Hi, I have attached an example section of the csv. There are two columns of data (from a spreadsheet), which are separated by a comma delimiter in the .csv. The first colum of file names are the ones that I need to search (i.e. NOT the KA* file names). Some of the file names do have spaces so this is something which need to be considered as someone else pointed out.

```
preservation stocklshots - 16ln916-963.mp4,KA0003773-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_ 16LN916-963.mp4,KA0003773-001.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_16LN679-738.mp4,KA0003775-002.mp4
PreservationStockshots_16LN679_738.mp4,KA0003775-001.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_16LN01-52.mp4,KA0003776-002.mp4
Preservation_Stockshots_16LN01_52.mp4,KA0003776-001.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_LN566-LN624.mp4,KA0004507-001.mp4
PreservationStockShots_LN566_LN624.mp4,KA0004507-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_LN675-LN705.mp4,KA0004508-001.mp4
PreservationStockshots_LN675_LN705.mp4,KA0004508-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_LN706-752.mp4,KA0004509-001.mp4
PreservationStockshots_LN706_LN752.mp4,KA0004509-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_LN930-LN972.mp4,KA0004511-001.mp4
PreservationStockShots_LN930_LN972.mp4,KA0004511-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_LN1023-LN1059.mp4,KA0004513-001.mp4
PreservationStockShots_LN1023_LN1059.mp4,KA0004513-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_LN1152-LN1220.mp4,KA0004515-001.mp4
PreservationStockShots_LN1152_LN1220.mp4,KA0004515-002.mp4
Preservation Stockshots_16LN320-379.mp4,KA0004517-001.mp4
Preservation_Stockshots_16LN320_379.mp4,KA0004517-002.mp4
```

Comment: I assume the csv only includes the file's *names*, not the paths?

Comment: updated my original post with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while IFS=, read -r file rest
do
  find /path/to/movies_dir -name "${file}" -exec cp '{}' /path/to/Sorted_Media/ \;
done < mylist.csv
```

That assumes file names don't contain wildcard characters (`?`, `[`, `*` or backslash).

Comment: yes, @StéphaneChazelas is right.. please see the modified code above

Comment: Presumably the reason the list is in a CSV file is that there are values ("V") separated ("S") by commas ("C").  A CSV file with only one column of data would be called a "list" (:

Comment: Unless the original poster provides a sample, my assumption is a single column csv, i.e. a list file.

Comment: updated my original post with this info.

Comment: The csv contains two separate value 'columns' separate by a comma. the first value is the filename which I am interested in (I've added an example to my initial query).

Comment: Thanks Mel, that has worked perfectly for my needs. Please could you explain how each section works so I have a better understanding for next time?

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that, for example, the CSV looks like this:

```
Spaceballs,/mnt/Movies/Comedy/Spaceballs.avi
Star Wars IV: A New Hope,/mnt/Movies/SciFi/starwars-4.avi
```

You can then do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEST=/path/to/SortedMedia
for file in $( cut -d, -f 2 /path/to/movielist.csv ); do
    cp "$file" $DEST/"${file##*/}"
done
```

Comment: Hello, no sorry, the csv doesn't contain file locations. The files are in subfolders under one main known folder so the script would have to recursively search for each file name without a specific address.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
files=(${(f)"$(cut -d , -f 1 <movies.csv)"})
glob=('$files['{1..$#files}']')
eval "tocopy=(Movies/**/(${(j:|:)glob})(D.))"
print -rl -- $tocopy # to  check it's OK
cp -i -- $tocopy Sorted_Media/
```

Explained:

- `cut -d , -f1 < movies.csv`: retrieve the first column of the csv (one file name per line).
- `${(f)"$(cmd)"}`: split the output of `cmd` on line feeds (`$files` is now an array with all the file names).
- `glob=('$files['{1..$#files}']')`: make another array with elements literally `$files[1]`, `$files[2]`...
- `${(j:|:)array}`: join the elements of the array with `|`, so we're basically evaluating the `tocopy=(Movies/**/($files[1]|$files[2]|...|$files[n])(DN.))` command (where `n` is the number of elements in the `$files` array).
- `**/`: recursive globbing (search for the files in any level of subdirectories).
- `(D.)`: glob qualifiers (search in hidden dirs as well (D), only regular files (.))

Or with GNU tools:

```
find Movies -type f -print0 |
  awk '
    !d {f[$1]; next}
    $NF in f {
      delete f[$NF]
      print
    }' FS=, file.csv d=1 FS=/ RS='\0' ORS='\0' - |
  xargs -r0 cp -vt Sorted_Media/
```

By using `delete`, we make sure only the first instance (if there are several files with the same name) is copied. `-i` in the zsh solution is to give you a chance to decide what to do if there's a conflict. We can't use `-i` here because `cp`'s stdin is no longer the terminal.

Replace `cp` with `echo cp` if you just want to check what it would be doing without actually doing it.

Comment: I wonder how hard would it be to implement (in `find`) something a la `rsync`'s `--files-from`... so e.g. `find . -names-from=...`  ?

Comment: @don_crissti, I don't expect it would be hard but then again, I'd expect it to do pattern matching which we don't want here. [related feature request currently on the findutils mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.findutils.bugs/6046).