# Pipe pattern input to find command

Tags: find

I have a scenario where I am trying to `find` multiple files based on the output of another command.

The command itself is

`./libopt -d test . 2>&1 | sed -rn 's/Cannot find library \"(.*?)\"/\1/p'`

and this gives me the following output

```
libopcodes-2.25-system.so
libbfd-2.25-system.so
libz.so.1
libdl.so.2
libc.so.6
libosal.so
libarchive.so.13
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libfreetype.so.6
libpng12.so.0
libpthread.so.0
libts-1.0.so.0
libgcc_s.so.1
libssl.so.1.0.0
libm.so.6
ld-linux.so.3
libxml2.so.2
libbz2.so.1.0
liblzma.so.5
liblzo2.so.2
libattr.so.1
libacl.so.1
libnettle.so.4
```

Is there anyway that I can feed this input to the following find command in order to find the location of each of these files?

```
find /usr -name <INPUT_LINE>
```

Comment: Related: [Search a directory recursively for files listed in a csv, and copy them to another location](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265808)

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that no problematic characters (e.g. those in `IFS`) exist in the library names, loop over the list and pass each to a new find:

```
./libopt -d test . 2>&1 | sed -rn 's/Cannot find library \"(.*?)\"/\1/p' \
| while read libname; do
  find /usr -name "$libname"
done
```

Otherwise, for a single filesystem pass (the above does one for each input file), the `find -name` option is not suitable for matching a list of filenames, so perhaps the output of a single filesystem search could be passed to `grep`. The search also could be narrowed by only looking in directories under `/usr` that are named `lib`:

```
./libopt -d test . 2>&1 | sed -rn 's/Cannot find library \"(.*?)\"/\1/p' > blah
find /usr/lib /usr/*/lib -type f | grep -F -f blah
```

Use a `mktemp` generated filename if `blah` is a problem. With a fancy shell, the file of patterns for `grep` could be generated on the fly via some form of process substitution.

Comment: if using `find | grep` you could save `./libopt` output to a file and use it with `find .. | grep -f filename`.  should probably use `-F` for fixed strings too.  this is much simpler than my method of constructing a long regexp first.

Comment: @cas yeah, `grep -f file` I something I keep forgetting about.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the filenames into a single regular expression and use `find`'s `-regex` or `-iregex` (case-insensitive) options.

```sh
libs=$(./libopt -d test . 2>&1 | 
       sed -rn 's/Cannot find library \"(.*?)\"/\1/p' | 
       xargs -r | sed -e 's/ /|/g ; s/\./\\./g')

[ -n "$libs" ] && find /usr -regextype egrep -iregex ".*/($libs)"
```

`xargs` puts all the filenames onto one line separated by spaces, and the following `sed` changes the spaces to `|` and `.` to `\.`.  The `find` command is only run if $libs is non-empty.

Note: if too many (thousands) of filenames are output by `./libopt`, the `xargs` command will output 2 or more lines, $libs will be too large to fit on one command line, and this will break.  If that is likely (it seems unlikely to me, given what `./libopt` is outputting), you could work around it by running the `xargs | sed` and `find` in a loop, for example:

```sh
libs=$(./libopt -d test . 2>&1 | sed -rn 's/Cannot find library \"(.*?)\"/\1/p')

for re in $(echo "$libs" | xargs | sed -e 's/ /|/g ; s/\./\\./g') ; do 
    find . -regextype egrep -iregex ".*/($re)"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
files=(
  ${(f)"$(./libopt -d test . 2>&1 |
          sed -rn 's/Cannot find library \"(.*?)\"/\1/p')"})
glob=('$files['{1..$#files}']')
eval "paths=(**/(${(j:|:)glob})(D.))"
ls -ld -- $paths
```

See this answer to a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265815 for an explanation and also some alternative approach if you don't have `zsh`.